# Typescrypt Compiler Api create as const assertion

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I want to create an array from string literals with the Typescript Compiler Api that looks like this:

```js
const myArray = ["entry1", "entry2"] as const
```

For the array itself Im using:

```js
const myArray = ts.factory.createVariableDeclarationList(
    [
      ts.factory.createVariableDeclaration(
        'myArray ',
        undefined,
        undefined,
        ts.factory.createArrayLiteralExpression([
          ts.factory.createStringLiteral('entry1'), 
          ts.factory.createStringLiteral('entry2')
        ])
      )
    ],
    ts.NodeFlags.Const
  )
```

Which results in `const myArray = ["entry1", "entry2"]`

How do I add the `as const` at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an `as` expression with a type reference to `const`:

```
const myArray = ts.factory.createVariableDeclarationList(
  [
    ts.factory.createVariableDeclaration(
      'myArray',
      undefined,
      undefined,
      ts.factory.createAsExpression(
        ts.factory.createArrayLiteralExpression([
          ts.factory.createStringLiteral('entry1'),
          ts.factory.createStringLiteral('entry2'),
        ]),
        ts.factory.createTypeReferenceNode('const')
      )
    ),
  ],
  ts.NodeFlags.Const
);
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know about any good resources other than the GitHub wiki ?

Comment: @Niro I just pasted the desired result into the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/Q) and used the AST viewer. Then I know what the nodes I need to create are called.

Comment: Thanks again, I was oblivious to the fact that the playground had an AST viewer.